Quant.SE University Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers
Lauren Gundrum, member of CHAOS, has offered to help any interested students and teachers with starting a pizza ambassadors program to help get the word out about this site.
Here's the description from Physics.SE:

StackExchange is looking for students and teachers who might be
  interested in helping us kick off/formalize a university pizza
  ambassador-type program. Physics.StackExchange would like to sponsor
  university students (college or graduate) and faculty members who are
  excited about Physics, Stack Exchange and free food. Contact Seth
  Rogers (email seth at stackexchange or drop a note in chat) for more
  details about the program and to get involved.
Students at all levels learn from these type of gatherings;
  interesting questions help Physics as a discipline and Stack Exchange
  as a growing resource.

Anyone interested should contact lauren@stackexchange.com.

is this program only meant to be carried in the US or is Europe in contention?

@SRKX Don't know, ask Lauren.

@SRKX it can be done in Europe.
